# add a property of object to combo box?

Tags: java, swing, list, combobox

I have list of objects(Artikel.java) and i add them to JComboBox.
I want a property(String name) of this object be in the list? i did as below but stil the object is in the list and it is not readable.

**how can i do it? Where is my problem?**

```
if (titel.equalsIgnoreCase("artikel")) {
            panel.lstArtikel = readFromArtikel();
            panel.cbxArtikel = new WebComboBox(new ComboBoxModelArtikel(panel, lstArtikel));
            panel.cbxArtikel.setAction(new ComboBoxArtikelActionListener(panel));
            panel.cbxArtikel.setRenderer(new ArtikelListRenderer());
            panel.artikelTabPanel.add(panel.cbxArtikel,   BorderLayout.NORTH);

}
```

**ComboBoxModelArtikel**

```
public class ComboBoxModelArtikel implements ComboBoxModel{
ConfigToolScannersPanel panel;   List<Artikel> lstArtikels; 
private Object selectedItem;

public ComboBoxModelArtikel(ConfigToolScannersPanel panel, List<Artikel> artikels) {
     this.panel=panel;  this.lstArtikels=artikels;      
      }
public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
    selectedItem=anItem;
      }
public Object getSelectedItem() {
    return selectedItem;
      }
public int getSize() {
    return lstArtikels.size();
      }
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return (Artikel)lstArtikels.get(index);
      }
public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
    //Todo:
      }
public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
    //Todo:
      }
    }
```

**ArtikelListRenderer()**

```
class ArtikelListRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    if (value != null) {
        Artikel artikels = (Artikel) value;
        setText(artikels.getName());
    } else{
        setText("Please select an item");
    }

    return this;
    }
 }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the problem in one class, and it seems to be working:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;

public class ComboMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JComboBox<Artikel> cmb = new JComboBox<Artikel>(
                new ComboBoxModelArtikel(null, readFromArtikel()));
        cmb.setRenderer(new ArtikelListRenderer());
        f.add(cmb);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static List<Artikel> readFromArtikel() {
        List<Artikel> a = new ArrayList<Artikel>();
        a.add(new Artikel("id", "name"));
        a.add(new Artikel("id1", "name1"));
        return a;
    }

}

class Artikel {
    String id;
    String name;

    public Artikel(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}


class ArtikelListRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Artikel> {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList<? extends Artikel> list, Artikel value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value != null) {
            Artikel artikels = (Artikel) value;
            setText(artikels.getName());
        } else {
            setText("Please select an item");
        }

        return this;
    }
}

class ComboBoxModelArtikel implements ComboBoxModel<Artikel> {
    private Object selectedItem;
    List<Artikel> lstArtikels;
    private Object panel;

    public ComboBoxModelArtikel(Object panel, List<Artikel> artikels) {
        this.panel = panel;
        this.lstArtikels = artikels;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        selectedItem = anItem;
    }

    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return lstArtikels.size();
    }

    public Artikel getElementAt(int index) {
        return lstArtikels.get(index);
    }

    public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        // Todo:
    }

    public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        // Todo:
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem is in the WebComboBox

Comment: He already has a custom renderer which is set on the combobox, which should just work. Most likely the error is located somewhere else (as in some part of the code that is not posted). Overriding a `toString` method to fix a UI problem is not something I would ever recommend

Comment: I agree with you Robin. I just suggested this as a starting point of going towards a proper solution

Comment: i get erro: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
 at be.azvub.j2eeoe.util.configtoolscanners.control.ArtikelListRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(TabbedPanChangeListener.java:235)
`

Comment: I edited the answer. I put all in one class, and it seems to work. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks it works. I did left on line of code in my model which returned string in place of Artikel and this was a problem. your recreation helped me.thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The default list cell renderer uses toString() for elements of unknown type. You can overload that in the Artikel class, but it is **not recommended**. It will work, but you would be overloading a general-purpose method to suit your Swing-specific purposes.

The correct way to do it is to supply you own implementation of `ListCellRenderer` [(doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html)).

Comment: I did see the code above. I get error in the `ArtikelListRenderer`  as class cast exeption.

Comment: Are you sure you are putting only objects of type Artikel in the list? Post the whole error message.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
 at be.azvub.j2eeoe.util.configtoolscanners.control.ArtikelListRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(TabbedPanChangeListener.java:234)
 at be.azvub.webutil.gui.wlaf.WebComboBoxUI.paintCurrentValue(WebComboBoxUI.java:130)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.paint(BasicComboBoxUI.java:848)
 at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:142)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:737)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1000)

Comment: at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:837)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1009)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:837)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1009)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:837)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1009)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:837)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1009)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:837)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1009)

Comment: at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:559)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:837)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1009)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintWithOffscreenBuffer(JComponent.java:4966)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintDoubleBuffered(JComponent.java:4919)
 at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4862)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4669)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:451)
 at

Comment: at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:110)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
 at be.azvub.webutil.gui.WebEventQueue.dispatchEvent(WebEventQueue.java:34)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
 at

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)

Comment: The code you posted should be working, but the error message indicates you are putting Strings in the list.

Comment: this actionPerformance shows that what i have in comboBox is object Artikel:`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  WebComboBox webComboBox = (WebComboBox) e.getSource();
//  String seletedItem = webComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
  Artikel seletedItem = (Artikel) webComboBox.getSelectedItem();
   panel.txtArtikelName.setText(seletedItem.getName());
   panel.txtArtikelDesription.setText(seletedItem.getDescription());
   panel.txtArtikelNumber.setText(seletedItem.getNumber());
  }`