# Why do i get class cast exception on ListCellRenderer of JComboBox in java?

Tags: java, swing, list, combobox

I have a custom combo box ListCellRenderer as below.

```
class ArtikelListRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,   boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Artikel artikels = (Artikel) value;
        setText(artikels.getName());
        return this;
    }
}
```

I add this render to combobox as below.

```
public void setUpArtikelComboBox() {
        panel.lstArtikel = readFromArtikel();
        panel.cbxArtikel = new WebComboBox(new ComboBoxModelArtikel(panel, lstArtikel));
        panel.cbxArtikel.setAction(new ComboBoxArtikelActionListener(panel));
        panel.cbxArtikel.setRenderer(new ArtikelListRenderer());
        panel.artikelTabPanel.add(panel.cbxArtikel,   BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Why do I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
```

in the ListCellRenderer class in line:

```
Artikel artikels = (Artikel) value;
```

Comment: [see duplicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770549/add-a-property-of-object-to-combo-box)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `ComboBoxModelArtikel` is your custom `ComboBoxModel` and it uses a `List` or another `Collection`.

I also assume that when calling

```
panel.cbxArtikel = new WebComboBox(new ComboBoxModelArtikel(panel, lstArtikel));
```

you correctly initialize the internal `List` (or other class that represents your model).

Do you have a

```
JList.setPrototypeCellValue(Object prototypeCellValue)
```

somewhere in your code and a `String` as a parameter? Your custom `ListCellRenderer` gets called with whatever you specify as `prototypeCellValue`

Answer (score 0):

It means that the "value" is not of type Artikel.

Comment: In this line `panel.cbxArtikel = new WebComboBox(new ComboBoxModelArtikel(panel, lstArtikel));` i add Artikel to comboBox. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I seems that your combo box model contains `String`s.

What is the source for WebComboBox and ComboBoxModelArtikel?

**edit:**

it seems to me that it's working as I would expect (I wanted to simulate your problem)...

There are 3 unanswered questions:

1. Why you want to use own rendered (ArtikelListRenderer) ?
2. Why you need to use own combo box (WebComboBox)?
3. Why are you asking same question multiple times (see @mKorbel's comment)?

```
package net.betlista.swing;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;

public class JComboBoxTest extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox cb;

    public JComboBoxTest() {
        super( "JComboBoxTest" );
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        initGUI();

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible( true );
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        initCB();
        this.add( cb );
    }

    private void initCB() {
        final Person[] data = { new Person( "A" ), new Person( "B" ) };
        final PersonComboBoxModel model = new PersonComboBoxModel( Arrays.asList( data ) );
        cb = new JComboBox( model );

        cb.setRenderer( new PersonRenderer() );
    }

    class Person {
        String name;

        public Person(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    class PersonRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent( final JList list, final Object value, final int index,
                final boolean isSelected, final boolean cellHasFocus ) {
            System.out.println( "class: " + ( value == null ? "" : value.getClass() ) );
            return new JLabel( String.valueOf( value == null ? "" : value ) );
        }
    }

    class PersonComboBoxModel implements ComboBoxModel {

        List<Person> list;
        int selected = -1;

        public PersonComboBoxModel(final List<Person> pl) {
            list = pl;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getElementAt( final int index ) {
            return list.get( index );
        }

        @Override
        public void addListDataListener( final ListDataListener l ) {
        }

        @Override
        public void removeListDataListener( final ListDataListener l ) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelectedItem( final Object anItem ) {
            list.indexOf( anItem );
        }

        @Override
        public Object getSelectedItem() {
            if ( 0 <= selected && selected < list.size() ) return list.get( selected );
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        new JComboBoxTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: No, panel is `Jpanel` and `lstArtikel` is `List<Artikel>`.

Comment: I added my implementation to simulate your problem, but it seems it works as I would expect. Please answer the questions above, because when you comment `cb.setRenderer( new PersonRenderer() );` it works IMHO identically.

Comment: Answer 1 - i want use an object in the comboBox otherways i can add string.
Answer 2 - WebComboBox is in the framework that i should use it.
Answer 3 - because i get crazy and i knew that my code is ok.
Finally thanks to you with your recreation i got to know what was wrong.